# Numba optimization

Tags: python, optimization, numba

I have a slow python function and i cannot make it faster with numba. What should i do?

```
char_vectors_numba = Dict.empty(
key_type=types.unicode_type,
value_type=types.float64[:],
)

X = np.zeros((1, 128, len(chars)), dtype=np.bool)
@njit()
def get_matrices(sentences, x=X[:]):
    max_sentence_len = 128
    for i, sentence in enumerate(sentences):
        char_seq: str = (START_CHAR + sentence + END_CHAR).ljust(max_sentence_len+1, PADDING_CHAR)
        for t in range(max_sentence_len-1):
            x[i, t, :] = char_vectors_numba[char_seq[t]]
    return x
```

It crashes with this error:

> The use of a `DictType[unicode_type,array(float64, 1d, A)]<iv=None>` type, assigned to variable `'char_vectors_numba'` in globals, is not supported as globals are considered compile-time constants and there is no known way to compile a `DictType[unicode_type,array(float64, 1d, A)]<iv=None>` type as a constant.

How to solve it?

Comment: Try moving the `char_vectors_numba` definition into inside the body of your function block (the error is saying it can't compile that as a global). Also, you are attempting to assign `char_vectors_numba[char_seq[t]]` (which is empty/unmodified according to your code) to your numpy array, when I think you may want to do it the other way around?

Comment: Alternatively, you could pass it as a parameter.